# Trying to produce a unique sequence of random numbers per iteration

Tags: c++, random

As the title states, I'm trying to create a unique sequence of random numbers every time I run this little program.

However, sometimes I get results like:

```
102
201
102
```

The code

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                srand (time(NULL)+i);
                cout << rand() % 3;
                cout << rand() % 3;
                cout << rand() % 3 << '\n' << endl;
        }
}
```

Clearly srand doesn't have quite the magical functionality I wanted it to. I'm hoping that there's a logical hack around this though?

Edit1: To clarify, this is just a simple test program for what will be implemented on a larger scale. So instead of 3 iterations of rand%3, I might run 1000, or more of rand%50.
If I see 102 at some point in its operation, I'd want it so that I never see 102 again.

Comment: The built-in "rand" library is not designed for security.

Comment: Move `srand` out of the loop. You should normally only call it once.

Comment: What is wrong with the results you are getting?

Comment: How many times do you plan to run this little program? There are only 27 distinct outputs it can possibly produce.

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve here? 102 seems random enough to me

Comment: For randomness GUID is the ultimate, other rand generator all depends on some random seeds and they are not 'truely'  random

Comment: @seccpur - unless you've a dedicated piece of hardware in your machine, GUID isn't 'truely' random either.  Have a read of https://www.random.org/

Comment: @UKMonkey: explain "dedicated piece of hardware" ? GUID use time, date and processor ID/mac ID , which every computer has, to generate GUID. A computer without processor  or timer is unthinkable

Comment: *"If I see 102 at some point in its operation, I'd want it so that I never see 102 again"* But why? When you throw a dice, and it comes up 6, do you expect it to never come up 6 again? That would suggest very strongly that the dice is loaded. It is perfectly normal and expected for a uniformly distributed random sequence to contain repeated subsequences - in fact, the probability of this happening tends to 1 as the length of the sequence increases. There are only so many distinct three-digit combinations, it's physically impossible to never repeat one.

Comment: @seccpur - it's off topic, but none of those you've listed are random; there's no way you've read and digested the link in 4 minutes, so I'll leave you to take a look.

Comment: @UKMonkey:Anyway thanks for the discussion was interesting tho

Comment: @seccpur quick example of dedicated hardware:  detect RF noise in atmosphere; detection of decay of radioactive particles

Comment: @UKMonkey: that probability would be too slimmed to be considered?

Comment: @seccpur Hence why I was correcting you for wanting something 'truely' random.  The GUID as you say is based upon a number of other seeds; which random generators can have access to anyway, and I suspect they (or a subset) are used by <random> anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, if you were going to use `srand`/`rand`, you'd want to seed it once (and only once) at the beginning of each execution of the program:

```
int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    cout << rand() % 3;
    cout << rand() % 3;
    cout << rand() % 3 << '\n' << endl;
}
```

Second, `time` typically only produces a result with a resolution of one second, so even with this correction, if you run the program twice in the same second, you can expect it to produce identical results in the two runs.

Third, you don't really want to use `srand`/`rand` anyway. The random number generator in `<random>` are generally considerably better (and, perhaps more importantly, are enough better defined that they represent a much better-known quantity).

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

int main() { 
    std::mt19937_64 gen { std::random_device()() };
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> d(0, 2);

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<3; j++)
            std::cout << d(gen);
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

Based on the edit, however, this still isn't adequate. What you really want is a random sample without duplication. To get that, you need to do more than just generate numbers. Randomly generated numbers not only can repeat, but inevitably *will* repeat if you generate enough of them (but the likelihood of repetition becomes quite high even when it's not yet inevitable).

As long as the number of results you're producing is small compared to the number of possible results, you can pretty easily just store results in a set as you produce them, and only treat a result as actual output if it wasn't previously present in the set:

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
    std::mt19937_64 gen { std::random_device()() };
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> d(0, 999);
    std::set<int> results;

    for (int i = 0; i < 50;) {
        int result = d(gen);
        if (results.insert(result).second) {
            std::cout << std::setw(5) << result;
            ++i;
            if (i % 10 == 0)
                std::cout << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

This becomes quite inefficient if the number of results approaches the number of possible results. For example, let's assume your producing numbers from 1 to 1000 (so 1000 possible results). Consider what happens if you decide to produce 1000 results (i.e., all possible results). In this case, when you're producing the last result, there's really only one possibility left--but rather than just producing that one possibility, you produce one random number after another after another, until you stumble across the one possibility that remains.

For such a case, there are better ways to do the job. For example, you can start with a container holding all the possible numbers. To generate an output, you generate a random index into that container. You output that number, and remove that number from the container, then repeat (but this time, the container is one smaller, so you reduce the range of your random index by one). This way, each random number you produce gives one output.

It *is* possible to do the same by just shuffling an array of numbers. This has two shortcomings though. First, you need to shuffle them correctly--a Fischer-Yates shuffle works nicely, but otherwise it's easy to produce bias. Second, unless you actually do use all (or *very* close to all) the numbers in the array, this is inefficient.

For an extreme case, consider wanting a few (10, for example) 64-bit numbers. In this, you start by filling an array with numbers from 2<sup>64</sup>-1. You then do 2<sup>64</sup>-2 swaps. So, you're doing roughly 2<sup>65</sup> operations just to produce 10 numbers. In this extreme of a case, the problem should be quite obvious. Although it's less obvious if you produce (say) 1000 numbers of 32 bits apiece, you still have the same basic problem, just to a somewhat lesser degree. So, while this is a valid way to do things for a few specific cases, its applicability is fairly narrow.

Comment: Hey Jerry, thanks a lot for taking the time to answer, especially with that third edit. I'd gotten stuck for a while but I'm pursuing the container approach you suggested, and having fun with it!

Answer (score 0):

Generate an array containing the 27 three digit numbers whose digits are less than 3.  [Shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) it.  Iterate through the shuffled array as needed, values will be unique until you've exhausted them all.

As other people have pointed out, don't keep reseeding your random number generator.  Also, `rand` is a terrible generator, you should use one of the better choices available in C++'s standard libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You are effectively generating a three digit base 3 number.  Use your RNG of choice to generate a base 10 number in the range 0 .. 26 and convert it to base 3.  That gives 000 .. 222.

If you absolutely must avoid repeats, then shuffle an array as pjs suggests.  That will result in later numbers being 'less random' than the earlier numbers because they are taken from a smaller pool.